# Attach to tmux session and run a command

Tags: tmux

How I can run a command in Tmux when I'm attaching to a session ?

I want attach and immediately run a command.

I read the docs, but found only send keys, which not suits my needs.

Comment: I wonder what you expect to happen if, for instance, the tmux session you attach to happens to be running `vi`.

Comment: It will run only the bash

Answer (score 10):

You can attach to a running tmux session and spawn a new window which runs a particular command:

```
tmux attach \; new-window vim
```

Note that this does not spawn vim in the pre-exsiting window - there is no facility for doing that, it doesn't really make sense: as @Falcon Momot points out, an existing window could be running anything, the only way to issue commands is "send keys".

Comment: Great answer! This must be obvious to most readers, but it took me a while to realize it, so just in case anyone else has the same question: the `\;` is an escaped semicolon, used here to separate two `tmux` commands (without escaping the semicolon `new-windows` would be treated as a new shell command).

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for a solution to this exact problem.  It can be done using 'set-buffer' and 'paste-buffer' commands

```
tmux att -t <session-name> \; set-buffer "<command>^M" \; paste-buffer
```

Here is a complete example :

```
# let's start with two sessions running bash
tmux new -s theOtherSession \; detach
tmux new -s astropanic \; rename-window main-window \; detach

# attach to the 'astropanic' session, run a directory listing, output
# current datetime, then detach. Note for carriage return (^M) type ^V^M
tmux att -t astropanic \; find-window main-window \; set-buffer "ls;date^M" \; paste-buffer \; detach

# reconnect to check status
tmux att -t astropanic
```

Comment: I did not manage to do `carriage return` as you said. I had to send the enter key like this: `tmux attach -t "$1" \; set-buffer "ls;date" \; paste-buffer \; send-keys C-m`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Basically you should name a window and make the name stick by adding `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` to your shell profile (this is important), then use this window only to run commands upon connecting. I use it to connect to a ssh host and then get my kerberos ticket at the start of the day. `ssh hostname -t "tmux a -t 0 \; select-window -t cmd \; set-buffer \"kinit -f -l 1d -r 30d^M\" \; paste-buffer \;"`. For convenience, give it a nice name and save it as a script in your path. :) Also note the ^M should be inserted by pressing C-v then Enter in your editor.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me what kind of command you want to run, a tmux command or a shell/OS command. Here's an example of each:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd

# give the session a name; makes it easier to reuse code lines
_SNAME=Generic

# start a whole new tmux session
tmux new-session -s $_SNAME -d -x 140 -y 35

# can set tmux options
tmux set-option -t $_SNAME default-path /opt/foo/build

# create a new window that's just a shell
tmux new-window -t $_SNAME -n build -d

# create a new window that's running a program
tmux new-window -t $_SNAME -n vim -d vim
```

This leaves the session unattached. If you want to attach to it, too, add this line at the end of the shell script:

```
# attach to the new session
tmux attach -t $_SNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out this to run mutt, for example

```
tmux has-session -t mail
if [ $? != 0 ]
then
tmux new-session -s mail -n mel_GMAIL -d "TERM=xterm-256color ; mutt -F $HOME/.mutt/muttrc_perso"
fi
lxterminal --command="tmux attach -t mail"
```

It checks the existence of a 'mail' session running, if not, it creates one and starts the application mutt;
finally it attaches to it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little script that starts or attach to Tmux and runs a command in it. Once the command has been executed, it'll exit Tmux.

```
#!/bin/sh -x
SESSION_NAME=foo

tmux has-session -t $SESSION_NAME 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  tmux new-session -d -s $SESSION_NAME "$*"
fi
exec tmux attach -t $SESSION_NAME
```

Usage example:

```
$ ./script-above 'echo hello world && sleep 10'
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function tmuxed {
    /usr/local/bin/tmux new-session -d -s bkp 2&>/dev/null
    /usr/local/bin/tmux send-keys "/Users/xxx/bin/thisscript backup" C-m
}

function backup {
    echo 'bla bla doing stuff'
}

$1
```

And run `/Users/xxx/bin/thisscript tmuxed`