# How do I correctly (re)set $DISPLAY?

Tags: terminal, x11, tmux, display, mobaxterm

I connect from a Windows PC to a Linux PC with ssh using MobaXTerm.

Within the ssh session, I have a tmux session with a few windows and panes.

The ssh session will typically disconnect after a few hours of inactivity (I've tried toying with what looked like relevant keep-alive settings in MobaXTerm, but it's never worked).

First-world problem: After starting a new ssh session and *reattaching to my existing tmux sessions*, the `$DISPLAY` variable will sometimes be set "incorrectly" - by which I mean, when I launch a GUI that uses X-Windows (e.g. Firefox), I'll get "cannot open display" error messages. E.g.:

```
$ firefox &
[1] 23077
$ Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:11.0
Error: cannot open display: localhost:11.0

[1]+  Exit 1                  firefox
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:11.0
```

Usually when I open a *new* terminal, I'll get the updated/correct value of `$DISPLAY` - from this terminal, I'll be able to successfully launch X-Window-using GUIs.

**Question: is there any way I can dynamically "update" the value of `$DISPLAY` in an *existing* terminal (i.e. a terminal that's been alive since before the ssh disconnection)?** I.e. I'd like to try avoid having to launch a new terminal just for the purpose of getting/discovering the new value of `$DISPLAY`.

I don't really have a solid understanding of what `$DISPLAY` represents - so I'd be grateful if someone could explain what it represents and does in the context of the described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISPLAY` is used by X clients (application programs) to find the corresponding X server to connect. It's of the form `hostname:displaynr.screennr`, but usually you only see something like `:0`, which means the first display of the X server running on `localhost`.

Using a hostname in there is not secure, because the X protocol is not encrypted. So `ssh` with X forwarding piggybacks on this schema by finding a free display number, usually 10 or larger, and pretending to be an X server at this display number. But in reality it just forwards the X protocol over the ssh connection to the X server running on the host where the ssh client was called.

So that's why you get different `DISPLAY` contents when you reconnect with `ssh` - each connection with `ssh` sets this variable, possibly to a different value.

This new correct value is visible *before* you attach to tmux. It's also visible when you open a new terminal, because a new terminal will copy the freshly set `DISPLAY` variable, while an old terminal will keep the `DISPLAY` variable it already has.

So if instead of attaching to tmux you run a self-written script, which reads out `DISPLAY`, attaches to tmux, and then sets `DISPLAY` in the existing sessions, you can automate what you need to do.

However, doing that with tmux doesn't seem to be straightforward. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86925/attach-to-tmux-session-and-run-a-command) is another question with a few suggestions how to do that that may work for you (or not).

Answer (score 2):

After you attach tmux, by default it will update `DISPLAY` in the session environment, but it can only apply this to new panes. To apply it to an existing pane you should be able to do something like:

```
eval "$(tmux showenv -s DISPLAY)"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you login to your network, use `-X`; (ex. `ssh -X name@11.11.111.111`).

The `-X` tells allows `ssh` to display your browser.